# Cloning admin pages like users.php

Tags: users, add-menu-page

In my project I want to make a new menu position which will be actually a copy of 'Users' page but with some additional filters/modifications. For example as a result I need to have another menu position above users called "Admins" which will show exactly same structured page but with only Admin users. It is for better/easier user experience for my client.

My question is how to do this? I know that there are functions like `add_menu_page` but using them like this (`users.php` as identifier):

```
add_menu_page( 'custom menu title', 'custom menu', 'users.php', 'myplugin/myplugin-admin.php', '', plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' ), 6 );
```

results in two menu positions which collapse and expand together, and I wanted them to work independently. I can also show content based on function but I don't know if there is any way to easily output content of whole users.php page?

Comment: Why do you need two `users.php` pages?

Comment: As I said it is for my client and that's just how he wanted it to be. The question here is not 'why' but 'how'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further research I have used [WP_List_Table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table) class for this. I had to add buttons and links myself to make it look like users.php but it wasn't much of work.